# Failed to start Load Kernel Modules for installing Ubuntu 18.04 on Raspberry 4

Tags: pi-4, kernel, software-installation, ubuntu

I tried to install Ubuntu 18.04 on Pi4.
I followed the link from ubuntu for pi.
After inserting the SD card with Ubuntu image, the error appeared after few lines with

> [FAILED] Failed to start Load Kernel Modules

I searched and got the same question in the link below, but still can not solve the issue.
Link:[askubuntu-FAILED to start load Kernel modules](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779251/what-to-do-after-failed-to-start-load-kernel-modules)

Please help. Thanks!!!

Comment: so you went through the answers and tried them all? - oh, wait "I followed some of above advice" - what did you try? what didn't you try? why didn't you try it?

Comment: and what's the output of `sudo systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service`

Comment: I did apt-get update
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get -f install, the error is still there. When I tried "sudo apt-get remove nvidia-*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo nvidia-uninstall" there was an error with nvidia-uninstall.

Comment: @JaromandaX output of "sudo systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service" is : Active: Failed (result: exit-code) Failed to find module 'parport', Failed to find module 'ib_iser' and Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.

Comment: Is your OS compatible with ARM?

Comment: Have a look in /etc/modules and try commenting out (using # at the start of the line) any lines that match the failed modules.  As for why they have gone - do not know may by error in update / install.

Answer (score 0):

`dist-upgrade` is the kiss of death on Ubuntu.

It tries to replace the Pi specific boot code and firmware with EFI code.